# How to add values to a list inside a dictionary of objects?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of objects. Then I created an empty List as an element of that dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, object> mydictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
mydictionary["names"] = new List<string>();
```

Then I try to add a name into the List, but couldn't.

```
mydictionary["names"].Add("Jack"); -> ERROR "object does not contain definition of Add"
```

How can I add values to this List?

 Note: I can't change the dictionary type. It must be <string,object>.

Comment: Avoid doing this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler only knows that the entries are of type `object`, at compile time it doesnt know that this object is one that supports `Add`. I mean what Add would that be? You could also have a BigInteger object and a database. SO the compiler doesnt know how to do

```
mydictionary["name"].Add()
```

because it doesn't know what Add to call, or even if the object has an Add. This is because c# is a statically typed language. You need to tell the compiler what the object is

```
((List<string>)mydictionary["name"]).Add()
```

ie cast the object to the right type.

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically mention the type of value, like

```
((IList<string>) mydictionary["names"]).Add("Jack");
```

or you can use [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)

```
(mydictionary["names"] as (IList<string>)).Add("Jack");
```

---

**Why?**

- Because you declared dictionary as a `<string, object>`.
- When you added key-value pair i.e. `mydictionary["names"] = new List<string>();`, the value get stored as an `object` not a `List`.
- This is the reason when you are trying to add any string to a list, dictionary value is not recognized as a list,
- We fixed this problem, by [type-casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) an object to a list.